# change class with ng-class multiple

Tags: angularjs, class, ionic-framework

i'm early for angularjs.

i have some list, if i click one of list, popup will display. and after i chose option on popup, popup will close and background list will change. untill now it's work for only first list. ( i think )

and i got problem, when I click the second list, background first list change class to.

This sample`my`
[work](http://plnkr.co/edit/sRMwfgzRo9GM7RSSSOGZ?p=preview)

How to change background one by one after click option popup?
Please help me, 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WCxKsxo0SCj5m9aVLxL9?p=preview), your problem is that you have one scope "class" item for your 2 items.
I separate it to 2 different scope value `class1` and `class2` and I switch the `chooseItem` via showPopup, and when you close the popup, I update the class1 and class2 according the chooseItem.

Comment: thanks for reply, i'm sorry. i mean, if i chose option popup background list will change. so i click first list -> popup -> popup close -> background change , if click second list -> popup -> popup close -> background second change but background first list keep red.
can if i change like this ? `if($scope.chooseItem == 0)
    {
         $scope.class1 = "red";
         $scope.class2 = "white";
    }
    else
    {
         $scope.class1 = "red";
         $scope.class2 = "red";
    }`

Comment: You can, or simply choose this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7nzrqD6SjRCWZ7sp97hh?p=preview

Comment: oke, i'll try it. whether this method includes a dynamic or still static? i mean, when to much list..

Comment: I don't understand your question.. what do you mean 'static' 'dynamic'??

Comment: if the list automatically incremented by one, so the final list to be added to the code like `ng-init="item3Clicked = false" ng-class="{'red':item3Clicked,'white' : !item3Clicked}"` .. ??

Comment: If you added item dynamic you have to use ng-repeat. keep a list in your conroller contains all the items, then the color background logic have to be change to this:                                                                                        `<a ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="itemSelected = false" class="item" ng-class="{'red':itemSelected,'white' : !itemSelected}" ng-click="showPopup(); itemSelected = true">
        <i class="icon ion-ios7-pricetags-outline"></i>
       {{item.somthings1)
        <span class="item-note">
         {{item.somthings2)
        </span>
      </a>`